# NameError: name PositiveSmallIntegerField is not defined

Tags: django, django-models, python-3.x

Django 1.5 & Python 3.2.3, on Ubuntu 12.04.

Very odd error when trying to syncdb my DB. I've got some fields that don't look wrong but Django's spitting out this error message when I run `python3 manage.py sqlall`..

```
NameError: name 'PositiveSmallIntegerField' is not defined
```

Huh? I tried Googling this, but there's not a single thing about it anywhere. So I'm guessing I've made some stupid mistake but I can't see it. My models.py looks like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Song(models.Model):
    own = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    heard = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
    release_date = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    style = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    featuring = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    listen = models.URLField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    highest_chart_pos = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    note = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
```

That's all there is to it, and I copy-n-pasted `PositiveSmallIntegerField` straight from the Django documentation so I know there isn't a typo in it that I'm overlooking. So, how is `PositiveSmallIntegerField` **not** defined?

Comment: is this where it is throwing an error ? It could be some place else ? Also, are you using django 1.5 virtualenv and due to some conflicts it is not recognizing?

Comment: That's where it's throwing up, yeah. I'n not in the virtualenv, just doing this on the commandline: `python3 manage.py sqlall` and it's the only app on the dev server, so I'm certain there's no other app's causing it.

Comment: Did you see where the error is coming from? Is it even pointing at your code? Your code would not throw a NameError... it's an AttributeError if you didn't spell it right or django didn't have it for some reason. So either Django has shipped with a bug, or your source doesn't look like that. Either way, the full traceback will answer these questions (please post them always)

Comment: I gave the full error above, there's no traceback. That is all of the code I had. Django didn't ship with a bug either, 'cause there's no problem in other apps on other dev servers using the same Django installed on this machine. That's why this is so confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing this in here because I found myself with the same error, creating a model for a 
song, too!

```
from django.db import models

class Track(models.Model):
  release  = models.ForeignKey('Release', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  position = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
  number   = PositiveSmallIntegerField()
  name     = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  length   = models.DurationField()
```

There is a slight difference, here. I left out the namespace of `models.` before my `PositiveSmallIntegerField`. It looks like you didn't do that, above, but maybe someone else with a similar error will made my mistake, too.

Here was my stacktrace:

```
(env) Cam@cambook:~/Sites/juke% python manage.py makemigrations playlists
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/Cam/Sites/juke/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/Cam/Sites/juke/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/Cam/Sites/juke/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/Cam/Sites/juke/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/Cam/Sites/juke/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/Cam/Sites/juke/playlists/models.py", line 60, in <module>
    class Track(models.Model):
  File "/Users/Cam/Sites/juke/playlists/models.py", line 63, in Track
    number   = PositiveSmallIntegerField()
NameError: name 'PositiveSmallIntegerField' is not defined
```